# Can we create a listener(trigger) inside a message hub?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, message-hub

I am trying to connect message hub and apache kafka. I have created the trigger in openwhisk, but I want to know if we can create the trigger in message hub itself.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately your question does not meet the requirements for good questions on stackoverflow and is likely to get closed.  See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking.    Can you elaborate with more details as to what you are trying to achieve?   I found this documentation about using openwhisk to create a trigger that listens to Message Hub - https://hub.docker.com/r/openwhisk/kafkaprovider/  Is that what you've done so far?  Exactly what are you trying to trigger?